# Determine local endpoint on Silverlight socket

Tags: silverlight, sockets

Is there any way to get the local end point of a connected Silverlight TCP socket without having to resort to asking the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I do not believe this is possible, for security reasons. Like you say, you'll need to request the REMOTE_ADDRESS from the hosting server.

Comment: Asking the server it is then.